# error with facebook login Xcode 6.4 swift

Tags: swift, parse-platform, xcode6

Whenever i run my application, i get the following error;

```
PFUserAuthenticationController authenticationDelegateForAuthType:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

I tried to look for PFUserAuthenticationController class but cant find it. Any help?

Comment: Please elaborate on your question, for example by specifying your iOS target (8/9), by providing the source code where you try to login and anything else you might think is relevant.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but after update "Parse frameworks" it worked!

You can download the SDK from [here](https://parse.com/docs/downloads).

The files I updated were:

```
- Bolts.framework
- Parse.framework
- ParseCrashReporting.framework
```

Before this error I also update

```
- ParseFacebookUtilsV4.framework
- ParseUI.framework
```

I downloaded Facebook SDk v 4.6 from [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/downloads)

Comment: But when i update with the new facebook sdk i get a linker error. Should i only update the Parse SDK?

Comment: @Beast could you update your answer to see the error? I also update my project with the new new sdk